# How can i unload a Password filter dll?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

My C# application registers password filter dll name in the "Notification Package" registry key. When i restarts machine system loads all dlls ,whose name are present in Notification package" key. If i remove registry entry made earlier, dll still remain loaded until i restart m/c. Is there any way to unload this dll when i remove registry entry, without need of restarting m/c ? This dll needs to be kept in System32 folder

Thanks

Comment: You would need to code a way to tell it to unload.

Comment: Which .net class or method can i use for this ?

Comment: Thats entirely up to you how you do it - thats part of the designing element

Comment: @BugFinder: DLLs do not unload themselves in general. The component that loaded the DLL tells it when to unload.

Comment: tnfour, this would be true if it wasnt loaded by the fact its a reg key, if you had myapp.exe sure, its loaded by that, and dropped on exit. However if its loaded at login, only way to get it out would be for it to come with a way of being unloaded.  Other than the fact this sounds like a bad way of trying to capture passwords

Comment: No, there is no way to unload the DLL.  You have to restart the machine after removing the name from the registry key.

Comment: @BugFinder: yes, in principle the DLL could provide a way for the user to trigger it to unload itself, but since Winlogon wouldn't know that you had done so it would continue to call functions in your DLL, and Windows would crash.